# How to read x number of characters from a text file progressively

Tags: java

I am trying to read x characters from a text file at a time, progressively. So if I had: aaaaabbbbbcccccabckcka and im reading 5 at a time I would get, aaaaa, bbbbb,ccccc, abckc and ka. The code I am using is:

```
            status =  is.read(bytes);
            text = new String(bytes);
```

where bytes is: bytes = new byte[5], I am calling these two lines of code till status becomes -1, the problem I am facing is, the output is not what I have mentioned above, but I get this:

aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc, abckc and kackc, notice the last segment 'kackc' is garbage, why is this happening ?

Note: that bytes is initialized once outside the reading loop.

Comment: Are you clearing your `byte array` on each iteration? You can notice that `last 3` characters of your last input, is not garbage, but the last 3 characters of your prevoius input.

Comment: @RohitJain I just tried zeroing it out and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution works for ASCII, but many characters in other encodings use more than one byte. You should use a `Reader` and a `char[]` instead of an `InputStream` and a `byte[]`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I need to clear my byte buffer every time I read new input, I just used a for loop to zero it out and it worked

Comment: That is totally the wrong solution. The *right* solution is actually to examine the return-value (as more than just a "status"), so you know how many bytes were actually read into `bytes`.

Comment: so the last return value before the -1, will have the number of characters read, then I can get the substring of that string?

Comment: Note that the above method is good only if you know who is creating the text files and what characters might appear in them. Not all encodings produce a single byte per character.

Comment: @MikeG: I recommend you read the documentation for this method; I think it should clear some things up for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29